# Is there a pressure dependent function for freezing points of water and carbon dioxide?

Tags: physical-chemistry, reference-request

I'm trying to determine whether or not certain compounds form solid ice at certain atmospheric pressures. These pressures vary significantly, from 0.001 atm to 800 atm. I understand that there is no equation relating the freezing points of all elements, but is there one or two that relate to carbon dioxide and water?

Ideally I'd like a Python function (or library) or equation where the input is atmospheric pressure or kPa.

Or, failing that, if someone could point me in the direction of a phase diagram for both compounds where I can input specific atmospheric pressure values and read a specific temperature for freezing point, that would be helpful as well.

Comment: Welcome to chemistry.se! If you have questions about how to beautify your posts, have a look at the [help]. Do you want to know more about this site, please take the [tour].|| I do not have the time to do more research, but maybe [this page](http://www.science.uwaterloo.ca/~cchieh/cact/c123/phasesdgm.html) can help.

Comment: I did a lot of research already but I couldn't find a very detailed phase diagram. The link you posted's phase diagram for CO2 is broken.

Comment: Sorry about that. Maybe [this helps for CO2](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.86.5922) and this might [help for water](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.92.255701)

Comment: Diagrams on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_dioxide

Comment: @Martin That link does not load.@Mithoron that's the first place I looked. Not detailed enough.

Comment: Both links to phys rev lett work for me.

Comment: It works now, strange. Still, it's behind a paywall.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For ice I melting pressure as a function of temperature:

$$\pi = 1- 0.626000 \times 10^6 (1- \theta^{-3}) + 0.197135 \times 10^6 (1- \theta^{21.2})$$

where

$\pi =$ (pressure in MPa)/0.000611657 MPa

$\theta =$ (temperature in kelvins)/273.16K

Source is [International Equation of the Pressure along the Melting and along the Sublimation Curve of Ordinary Water substance](http://www.nist.gov/data/PDFfiles/jpcrd477.pdf) (no paywall).

For carbon dioxide:

$$\frac{p_m}{p_n} = 1 + a_1 (\frac{T}{T_t}) + a_2 (\frac{T}{T_t})^2$$

Where:

$T$ is temperature in kelvins

$T_t =$ 216.592K

$p_m$ is the melting pressure in MPa

$p_n =$ 0.51795 MPa

$a_1 =$ 1955.5390

$a_2 =$ 2055.4593

Source is [A New Equation of State for Carbon Dioxide...](http://www.nist.gov/data/PDFfiles/jpcrd516.pdf) (no paywall)

Check original sources before using equations in case I made typo(s).

Comment: Thanks! What exactly is P_sub_n? If I had an atmosphere of 0.006 atm or 0.00060795 MPa, would P_sub_n be 0.00060795? If I solve for T, would that give the temperature that C02 freezes at at at that pressure?

Comment: I'm not a Chemist, and unfortunately beyond Wolfram Alpha I don't know how to use these equations.

Comment: @anarchy8 p_n is the triple point pressure, the pressure at which gas, liquid and solid are in equilibrium.  P_m is the melting point pressure, so 0.00060795 in your example.  The co2 equation you could solve for t/t_t using the quadratic formula or a program like wolfram, or you could construct a table of values and interpolate the table.